# PaLM API and json

Tags: json, powershell, palm

I am trying to execute the following command in powershell:

`curl "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta3/models/text-bison-001:generateText?key=AIzaSyAxHrnH91lSLOeaWs5Rda1_PTn-OnWN9Kg" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{ "prompt": { "text": "Write a story about a magic backpack"} }'`

but receiving the following error:

```
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:140
+ ... SLOeaWs5Rda1_PTn-OnWN9Kg" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I tried the following command as some of them said to.

`Get-Command curl`

```
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

but Invoke-WebRequest also did not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this:

```
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:140
+ ..." -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It looks like PowerShell's `curl` doesn't support the same args as Linux's `curl`.

I would either switch to WSL to use real `curl`, or use native PowerShell like so:

```
Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Method POST `
  -Uri "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta3/models/text-bison-001:generateText?key=DO_NOT_SHARE_YOUR_KEY_ON_THE_INTERNET_EVER" `
  -Body '{ "prompt": { "text": "Write a story about a magic backpack"} }' `
  -ContentType "application/json"
```